# Unmarshalling error when I call WS

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I am trying to call a WS (I am sorry, but I can't copy here the WSDL. It's confidential :\ ). My invocation is:

```
CreateRequestResponse crr = servicioModificacion.createRequest(cr);
```

`servicioModificacion` has been initialized with:

```
servicioModificacion = new ModifyServiceServiceStub();
```

`ModifyServiceServiceStub` is:

```
public class ModifyServiceServiceStub extends org.apache.axis2.client.Stub implements ModifyServiceService { ... }
```

`ModifyServiceService`class is a simple interface:

```
public interface ModifyServiceService { ... }
```

`cr` object is implemented:

```
CreateRequest cr = new CreateRequest();
```

`CreateRequest`class is:

```
public  class CreateRequest implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean{ ... }
```

Ok. So, when I launch this line, I get a `org.apache.axis2.AxisFault` exception with the message `Unmarshalling Error:`. Nothing more. I've googled many and I don't find nothing similar (similar errors has a larger message, with more info.).

I've build the client with Apache Axis2: `Apache Axis2 version: 1.6.2  Built on : Apr 17, 2012 (05:34:40 IST)`

Anyone knows what can I do with this exception?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The problem was the soap XML that I was sending. I put it on SoapUI and I had the same error message, so I made a mockup XML and I compared them. Finally, I found that one of the params could not be null.